# Is this enough to prove a homeomorphism? -- inverse on a dense subset

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that a map $f:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism, I know that $A$ is compact. I am not sure whether it is enough to show that:

1. $f$ is continuous and injective
2. for all $y\in B_1$, there is a pre-image $f^{-1}(y)\in A$; here, $B_1$ is a dense subset of $B$.

**Now I have this, can I conclude that $f$ is a bijection?** Because then I can show that:

3. If $f(A)=B$ then $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

Therefore the statement I want to be true is: *Let $f:A\to B$ be a continuous injective map such that $f(A)$ is dense in $B$. Suppose that $A$ is compact. Then $f(A)=B$.*

Comment: But continuous bijective doesn't guarantee homeomorphism. Just consider the identity map from $\mathbb{X}\to \mathbb{X}$, where the first has discrete topology, which the second has trivial topology and $X$ by a finite set.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Sorry I was not clear. I do have a proof that in my particular case, the 3rd item is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $b\in B$, since $f(A)$ is dense, then every neighborhood of $b$ intersects $A$. Since $A$ is compact, $f$ is continuous, $f(A)$ is compact, hence closed. Thus $b\in f(A)$ otherwise we have an open set $G$ containing $b$ s.t. $G\cap f(A)=\emptyset$, which contradicts your assumption. So your statement holds.

But please be careful that continuous bijection from compact domain doesn't imply homeomorphism, as I pointed out in the comment.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that the problem is eventually simple, and all that needs to be said is that continuous image of a compact is a compact. Thanks for your help anyways for sure!